# Filter data from an 0bservable between date start date end

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, filter, observable

I'm getting an Observable from Firebase.

**How to filter the data from an Observable with a start date and end date?**

I need to get only the data of a period, so I need to make a filter inside an Observable, returning only the data between the in period informed.

Within my Observable on every given data, I have the date_anniversary and I need to return all the data between start_date and end_data based on the date_anniversary that is returned.

How do I filter and update Observable to only show data between start_date and end_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html#example-3-filter-for-number-greater-than-specified-value) of *filtering for number greater than specified value* from www.learnrxjs.io:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit every second
const source = interval(1000);
//filter out all values until interval is greater than 5
const example = source.pipe(filter(num => num > 5));

/*
  "Number greater than 5: 6"
  "Number greater than 5: 7"
  "Number greater than 5: 8"
  "Number greater than 5: 9"
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val =>
  console.log(`Number greater than 5: ${val}`)
);
```

So, in your case just filter result for the given range of dates:

```
source.pipe(filter(item => item.date_anniversary >= start_date && item.date_anniversary <= end_date));
```

I assume, that dates are in timestamp integer format, if it is in `JS Date` format, you may use its `getTime()` method.

If you have `moment JS` library loaded, you could use its [`isBetween()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

> Version 2.13.0 introduces inclusivity. A [ indicates inclusion of a value.

To make `moment.isBetween` inclusive, pass a fourth parameter:

> moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '()'); //false
>   moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '[)'); //true
>   moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '()'); //false
>   moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '(]'); //true
>   moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', null, '[]'); //true`

Comment: I'm using moment, but I think the isBeetween () function will not work correctly for what I need.

date_anniversary - date_inico - date_final

moment ('2018-03-10') isBetween ('2018-03-10', '2018-03-30') = false
moment ('2018-03-11') isBetween ('2018-03-10', '2018-03-30') = true

It is returned true only if the date is between the two dates which is start_date and end_date, but I need to return also when it is the same ...

Comment: Version 2.13.0 introduces inclusivity. A `[` indicates inclusion of a value. So try to add `[]`, like `isBetween ('2018-03-10',  '2018-03-30', null, '[]')`

Comment: Okay, so now it returns true when the date is the same or is between start_date and end_date, very good! Thank you!

Comment: Is the date of the database coming in DD / MM / YYYY format, isBetween () function only accepted in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: I did not test it, bu t you can always "help" moment to understand the  format by passing it as second parameter if needed, something like: `moment('18/03/1975', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: Yes, I am helping the moment to understand, the isBetween () function does not understand dates in the DD / MM / YYYY format, I thought there was a way to not need to do moment ('18 / 03/1975 ',' DD / MM / YYYY '), thank you.

Comment: To work correctly I had to create two variables like this: var date1 = moment (this.date_start, 'DD / MM / YYYY'). Format ('YYYY-MM-DD'), if you just do this: moment('18/03/1975', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), the isBetween () function can not validate correctly, this constrains the code but it works: D